# Hadoop: Why are job.setOutputKeyClass and setOutputValueClass explicitely required?

Tags: hadoop

To configure a hadoop job, we have to explicitely specify the following:

```
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class)

job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class)
```

However, the "mother class"already says that the output key and value are `Text` and `IntWritable`.

```
public class MyReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> ...
```

It also can be found in the prototype of the reduce function we override

```
@Override
public void reduce (final Text key, final Interable<IntWritable> values, ...
```

So my question is: why is it required to explicitely configure it when setting up the job, while it is already said in other places?

Moreover, if , let say I want an output value of type `LongWritable`, can I do it?

PS: Newbie in hadoop here so I may have missed something. If you have a nice doc about how hadoop works inside, feel free to share (I am still with bad french doc and edureka videos)

Comment: I believe the answer involves "type erasure" or something about not knowing which class is passed in place of the generic type, so it must be specified by the Job. And yes, the output can be any writable type